# is it possible to send key via bluetooth from android to android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there any programming way to send keys to call a number in android?
I want to pair an android device with another one like pairing bluetooth-headset and do what headsets do like calling or rejecting calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bluetooth hands-free profile specification (HFP) contains two roles: Audio Gateway (AG) and Hands-Free unit (HF).
Your android phone is the AG.
If you have a bluetooth chipset and stack that supports the HF role as well, this could possibly be done. But as far as I know, there are no phones that support the HF role.

Comment: You mean the sender chipset does NOT support that kinda data transferring?

Comment: You will have to look up the chipset in question on the BT SIG qualified listings to be sure (Bluetooth.org) But yes, there is a high propability that the device does not support this.

Comment: But there are some apps which controls the others via bluetooth protocol. Why not possible? So how have they achieved it?

Comment: Just want to make sure that I understand what you are asking here. Do you want to use two phones, one as HF and one as AG?

Or do you want to use one phone as AG and another device (a carkit or headset for example) as HF?

Comment: I want to use a device for remoting like sending commands as a bluetooth handsfree. And the other as a host to receive commands for executing? And i dont want to use third party apps

Comment: https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluetooth.org%2Fdocman%2Fhandlers%2Fdownloaddoc.ashx%3Fdoc_id%3D41181&ei=5AsMVdGCMYb4UPumgbgH&usg=AFQjCNE9PTm9V6FA5s1nqZ_W7RNP2dDHoA&sig2=eflb7iDlyX97bAZGSu0cDw&bvm=bv.88528373,d.d24

Here is the specification of the HFP, that should give you some insight in how the profile works.

If the "device" that you want to remote control the android phone supports HFP HF it will be possible to do this.

In that case, you will need to go to Bluetooth.com for implementation help.

Comment: Both of them are android. Thanks to reply